# impossible to encrypt a password in a multi-step form with bcrypt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm a beginner in ruby on rails and I have a problem encrypting a password in my registration form.
 I installed the bcrypt gem but I don't understand why the form doesn't work...

**my form model :**

```
module Wizard
    module User
        STEPS = %w(step1 step2 step3).freeze

        class Base
            include ActiveModel::Model
            include ActiveModel::SecurePassword

            attr_accessor :user    
            has_secure_password

            delegate *::User.attribute_names.map { |attr| [attr, "#{attr}="] }.flatten, to: :user

            def initialize(user_attributes)
                @user = ::User.new(user_attributes)
            end
        end

        class Step1 < Base
            validates :firstName, presence: {
                message: 'Un prénom doit être renseigné'
            }, length: { maximum: 50, 
                too_long: '50 caractères maximum pour le prénom' }
            validates :lastName, presence: {
                message: 'Un nom doit être renseigné'
            }, length: { maximum: 50, 
                too_long: '50 caractères maximum pour le nom' }
            VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
            validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255,
                too_long: '255 caractères maximum pour l\'adresse mail' },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX,
                message: 'Vous devez saisir une adresse mail valide' }
        end

        class Step2 < Step1
            validates :password, presence: true, length: { in: 8..15 }, length: { in: 8..15 }
        end

        class Step3 < Step2
            validates :school, presence: true
            validates :typeOfTeacher, presence: true
            validates :yearsOfExperience, presence: true
        end
    end
end
```

**My model User.rb :**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :firstName, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    validates :lastName, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
              format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
              uniqueness: true
    has_secure_password
    validates :password, presence: true
    validates :school, presence: true
    validates :typeOfTeacher, presence: true
    validates :yearsOfExperience, presence: true
end
```

**My controller :**
When saving the user in my create function. The registration stops because of the password.
 I think I'm using wrong has_secure_password.

```
class WizardsController < ApplicationController
before_action :load_user_wizard, except: %i(validate_step)

def validate_step
    current_step = params[:current_step]

    @user_wizard = wizard_user_for_step(current_step)
    @user_wizard.user.attributes = user_wizard_params
    session[:user_attributes] = @user_wizard.user.attributes

    if @user_wizard.valid?
        next_step = wizard_user_next_step(current_step)
        create and return unless next_step

        redirect_to action: next_step
    else
        render current_step
    end
end

def create
    if @user_wizard.user.save
        session[:user_attributes] = nil
        redirect_to letsgo_path
    else
        redirect_to({ action: Wizard::User::STEPS.first } )
    end
end

private

def load_user_wizard
    @user_wizard = wizard_user_for_step(action_name)
end

def wizard_user_next_step(step)
    Wizard::User::STEPS[Wizard::User::STEPS.index(step) + 1]
end

def wizard_user_for_step(step)
    raise InvalidStep unless step.in?(Wizard::User::STEPS)

    "Wizard::User::#{step.camelize}".constantize.new(session[:user_attributes])
end

def user_wizard_params
    params.require(:user_wizard).permit(:firstName, :lastName, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :school, :typeOfTeacher, :yearsOfExperience)
end

class InvalidStep < StandardError; end
```

end

**My view :**

```
<div class="div_Signup">
    <div class="div_SignupBlock">
        <%= render 'navbarSignup' %>
        <div class="div_SignupBlockInt">
            <div class="div_SignupText">
                Inscription
            </div>
            <div class="div_SignupTextName">
                Choisissez un mot de passe
            </div>
            <div class="div_SignupForm">
                <%= form_for @user_wizard, as: :user_wizard, url: validate_step_wizard_path do |f| %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag :current_step, 'step2' %>
                    <div class="div_SignupInputPassword">
                        <%= f.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Mot de passe', :class => field_class(@user_wizard, :password) %>
                        <% @user_wizard.errors[:password].each do |message| %>
                            <p style="color: red;"><%= message %></p>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div_SignupInputPasswordConfirmation">
                        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirmation du mot de passe', class: 'input_Signup' %>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <%= f.submit 'Suivant', class: 'button_Signup' %>
                <% end %>
        </div>
        <footer class="footer_Signup">
            <%= render 'footerSignup2' %>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I test my form when entering a password, I get error messages that show that the password cannot be empty,
 and the password confirmation field does not work.
However, I see that the password has been encrypted.
**Thanks !!!**

Comment: Are you aware that the password that was entered is not persisted to the database? But the password_digest is stored into the database. That means your validation for password presence will fail in each step unless the step in which the user actually enters a new password. Therefore you must validate that a password_digest exists. And the validation for the length doesn't make much sense in this context

Comment: `has_secure_password` already adds validations: presence, length and confirmation, you don't need to add your own validation, in your case they are enough https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password